# Jekyll custom collection hook

Tags: ruby, collections, jekyll, hook

This problem is bothering me for a while now.

The generated Jekyll site does show the right collections and all it's info on the desired pages. But all collections other than the (default) `posts` collection can't be used in a ruby plugin.

### Case:

We have a blog site using Jekyll.
To enrich the blog posts with author info and vice-versa there are some custom plugins using `Jekyll::Hooks.register`

The blog posts are written in markdown language and all contain some info in YAML format:

```
---
layout: post
authors: [author]
title: 'title'
intro: a short intro text
image: /path/to/image.png
tags: [jekyll, collections]
category: Programming
comments: true
---
```

This is the code for enriching the post with author information:

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_read do |site|
    puts 'Enriching posts with link to authors'

    site.posts.docs.each { |post|
        post.data['authors'].collect! { |author_username|
            site.data['authors'][author_username]
        }.compact!
    }
end
```

### Next step:

I updated the site with two more collections since we also want to show the training courses and talks that will be given.

Both collections contain a few files in markdown format with a same kind of YAML info at the top of the file.

```
---                               ---
layout: talk                      layout: training
speakers: [author]                trainers: [author]
title: Title                      title: Title
subtitle: Subtitle                subtitle: Subtitle
duration: 120 minutes             duration: 180 minutes
level: beginner                   level: intermediate
image: /path/to/image.png         image: /path/to/image.png
tags: []                          tags: []
category: Talks                   category: Training
comments: false                   comments: false
---                               ---
```

And I added the collections to the `_config.yml`

```
collections:
  training:
      output: true
      permalink: /training/:path/
  talks:
      output: true
      permalink: /talks/:path/

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "training"
      type: training
    values:
      layout: training
  - scope:
      path: "talks"
      type: talks
    values:
      layout: talk
```

### Desired implementation:

Now I want to enrich the talks and training courses with the authors as well.

Since the posts, talks and training files are all in a collection, I assume that changing the `posts` object to `talks` or `training` should obtain the desired objects and loop through them.

So I changed the custom plugin to this:

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_read do |site|
    puts 'Enriching posts with link to authors'

    site.posts.docs.each { |post|
        post.data['authors'].collect! { |author_username|
            site.data['authors'][author_username]
        }.compact!
    }

    site.talks.docs.each { |talk|
        talk.data['authors'].collect! { |author_username|
            site.data['authors'][author_username]
        }.compact!
    }
end
```

But then I get this error:

```
jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  undefined method `talks' for #<Jekyll::Site:0x00007f9325268e90>
```

The thing that is bothering me is that when I log the collection contents I get the following result: (formatted to json structure for better readability)

```
{
  "posts"=>
    #<Jekyll::Collection @label=posts docs=[
      #<Jekyll::Document _posts/2017-02-01-page1.md collection=posts>, 
      #<Jekyll::Document _posts/2017-02-02-page2.md collection=posts>,
      #<Jekyll::Document _posts/2018-04-04-page3.md collection=posts>
    ]>, 
  "training"=>
    #<Jekyll::Collection @label=training docs=[
      #<Jekyll::Document _training/page1.md collection=training>, 
      #<Jekyll::Document _training/page2.md collection=training>, 
      #<Jekyll::Document _training/page3.md collection=training>
    ]>, 
  "talks"=>
    #<Jekyll::Collection @label=talks docs=[
      #<Jekyll::Document _talks/page1.md collection=talks>, 
      #<Jekyll::Document _talks/page2.md collection=talks>, 
      #<Jekyll::Document _talks/page3.md collection=talks>
    ]>
}
```

As far as I can tell, both the `talks` and the `training` collection are in the same level and data structure as the `posts` collection.

### Question:

How can I accomplish to obtain the talks/training collection in my custom plugin so I can enrich the data with the author information.

I reduced the files and output for readability. Full codebase is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/Ordina-JTech/Ordina-JTech.github.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548376/david-jacquel) pointed me in the right direction.

I had to loop over the collections

```
site.collections.each do |collection|
  collection.each do |item|
    if item.respond_to?("each")
      item.docs.each do |post|
        if post.data['authors']
          post.data['authors'].collect! { |author_username|
            site.data['authors'][author_username]
          }.compact!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I still find it strange that the other collections aren't available on the `site` object.

But this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look into `site.collections`.

This can do the trick :

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_read do |site|

    ['posts', 'talks'].each do collection{
        site.collections[collections].docs.each { |talk|
            talk.data['authors'].collect! { |author_username|
                site.data['authors'][author_username]
            }.compact!
        }
    }

end
```

Comment: This didn't do the trick, but you got me in the right direction! Thank you for that.